# How to make artisan migrate command use database.php instead of .env

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

By default Laravel's `artisan migrate` command uses .env file to load database config from but how to make it look at database.php instead of .env file to load database connection information?

If I remove db credentials from .env file it gives me following error:

> [InvalidArgumentException] 
>   Database [mysql] not configured.

Though database.php has correct connection details.

Comment: You mean `config/database.php` has your database connection details hardcoded? It should [look like this](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/database.php#L55-L67), where the config file is loading from the `.env` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this from your **.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=new
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=''
```

Go to database.php in your config folder

and edit this **From**

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
```

**TO**

```
'default' => 'mysql',
```

if you are using another database (sqlite or sqlserv for exemple, change the default)

AND Dont forget to change the **credentials**

**mysql exemple :**

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'database',
            'username'  => 'username',
            'password'  => 'password',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
            'engine'    => null,
        ],
```

**in short :** you need to remove the database related variables from your `.env` file and change the `env('DB_HOST', 'localhost')` or anything similar in your database.php  to a simple text between ''

Comment: I am assuming that database.php will be a file which will be versioned and I don't think it is good idea to keep credentials in those files as one will have to edit them on each environment (local, staging and production) thus I believe reading them from environment is better idea. I have read this on laravel communities in past and I agree with them based on my own experiences.

Comment: yes i kinow , i just answered your question! when you do as i said , and use php artisan migrate , it will use the database.php and not the .env

Answer (score 3):

You can use `--database` to specify the database connection to use:

```
php artisan migrate --database=pgsql
php artisan migrate --database=mysql
php artisan migrate --database=sqlite
```